# How to select RANK over condition (depending previous row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

#### What we have

I have table like this

```
id          PlayerId    Amount
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           10
2           1           20
3           1           30
4           1           40
5           1           40
11          1           20
13          1           20
15          1           40
14          2           19
12          2           10
6           2           1
7           2           5
8           2           10
9           2           20
10          2           30
```

I have to select only rows where amount greater than previous row amount (per player).

So here is a query

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.PlayerId,
       a.Amount,
       a.PreVval,
       a.NextVal
 FROM (SELECT id,
       PlayerId,
       Amount,
       LAG(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id) PreVval,
       lead(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id) NextVal
       FROM dbo.Bets ) a 
       WHERE a.Amount > a.PreVval OR a.Amount < a.NextVal OR (a.PreVval IS NULL AND a.Amount < a.NextVal)

ORDER BY a.PlayerId, a.id
```

```
id          PlayerId    Amount      PreVval     NextVal
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           10          NULL        20
2           1           20          10          30
3           1           30          20          40
4           1           40          30          40
13          1           20          20          40
15          1           40          20          NULL
6           2           1           NULL        5
7           2           5           1           10
8           2           10          5           20
9           2           20          10          30
10          2           30          20          10
12          2           10          30          19
14          2           19          10          NULL
```

#### Question

So now i need to select sets where increase step count > 4 , i mean 1,2,3,4 for player 1 and 6,7,8,9,10 for player 2

Query should run over 15m rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query is an example where you can set the "step_count".

```
WITH Bets(id,PlayerId,Amount)
AS
(
SELECT 1,1,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,20 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,30 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1,40 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,1,40 UNION ALL
SELECT 11,1,20 UNION ALL
SELECT 13,1,20 UNION ALL
SELECT 15,1,40 UNION ALL
SELECT 14,2,19 UNION ALL
SELECT 12,2,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,2,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,2,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 8,2,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 9,2,20 UNION ALL
SELECT 10,2,30
)
,split_ranges
as(
select *,case when lag(amount) over(partition by playerid order by id) > amount
               or lag(amount) over(partition by playerid order by id) is null 
              then row_number() over(partition by playerid order by id)
          end as rnk_val
  from bets
   )
,groups_data
 as(
select *
       ,max(rnk_val) over(partition by playerid order by id) as fill_ranges
 from split_ranges
   )
select * from (   
select *,count(*) over(partition by playerid,fill_ranges) as cnt
  from groups_data
   )x
where x.cnt>=4
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bd815da2cbfa8f65bc999e5736f2041

Comment: Great!, i even can select max fill_range count for each player
however performance is very poor

Comment: check this one [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29cbed7c75522a6a847e8801294b5a80)

It's very fast but there is no opportunity to get max fill range

my query executes in 30 second and your's in 2.30 minutes

Comment: that link doesnt execute?.  Besides i coded so you have the ability to set up the step_count which is what you had asked mkRabbani?

Comment: there is not data simply
. however i will use your solution, thank you very much
i just edited the condition > to >= to avoid equal numbers, they shoud not taked as consecutive
What was the surprise for me is that
max(rnk_val) over(partition by playerid order by id) as fill_ranges
returnes max rnkval for rows before that row, it's really surprised me
again thank you very musch

Comment: Mark this answer as closed if this solved your problem please.

Answer (score 0):

The following logic is bit tricky, but you can check this out-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1437ac6cee8787a529b325988cd723b)

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT id,
        PlayerId,
        Amount,
        LAG(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id) PreVval,
        lead(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id) NextVal,

        ISNULL(LAG(ID,3) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id),0) LAG3,
        ISNULL(LAG(ID,2) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id),0) LAG2,
        ISNULL(LAG(ID,1) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id),0) LAG1,

        ISNULL(LEAD(ID,1) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id),0) LEAD1,
        ISNULL(LEAD(ID,2) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id),0) LEAD2,
        ISNULL(LEAD(ID,3) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerId ORDER BY id),0) LEAD3
        FROM Bets 
    ) a 
    WHERE a.Amount > a.PreVval 
    OR a.Amount < a.NextVal 
    OR (a.PreVval IS NULL AND a.Amount < a.NextVal)
)

SELECT id,PlayerId,Amount,PreVval,NextVal
FROM CTE A
WHERE ID-LAG3 = 3
OR LEAD1 - LAG2 = 3 
OR LEAD2 - LAG1 = 3
OR LEAD3 - ID = 3
```

Comment: this is wrong query,  it returns wrong result, also you can not connect Id because it's just PK identity. we need to select 1,2,3,4 rows for player 1 and 6,7,8,9,10 for player 2

Comment: I just do the opposite. Wait a min.

Comment: @KhorenMansuryan you can check the updated query and DEMO now.

Comment: semms working
But i am not sure how fast would be this query over 15m rows

Comment: also how about changing count =4 to count = 10, i have to add more 10+ lines to query

Comment: id 6 for player 2 is there. Not sure you are talking about which row.

Comment: I have use checking with 3 as you are looking for 4 consecutive row. You can change the value 3 to any value as per requirement. but just need to adjust the selection of LAG and LEAD accordingly.

Comment: yes, you are right, i have tested with real data, and it's enaught fast. only thing is if i want to change 4 to any number, i have to edit query and add lag4, lead4, lag5, lead5 and like this

Comment: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e755c309576d510b1f2bf9e415c5519c) 

check this out, t have changed data, and it's not working correctly

Comment: Upto level 5, you should be able to check till 6 consecutive number. As i am not infront my laptop now, i can chek the demo later.

Comment: Where condition will be something like -   WHERE ID-LAG5= 5
OR LEAD1 - LAG4 = 5
OR LEAD2 - LAG3 = 5
OR LEAD3 - lag2 = 5 or lead4 - lag1 = 5 or lead5 - id = 5

Comment: Sorry as i typed the last comment from mobile and code may be not well formared. But this should help.

Comment: thank you for your time, when you weill be able to check demo, please check it , because for another set of result, it's not working

Comment: Also LAG(ID) or LEAD(ID) would be wrong, because Id is just auto identity column, and no guarantee that it is sequential
i am sure there shoud be LAG(amount) and LEAD(amount)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=893c28dc7f0255392af7352249dccd2b Check this link I have considered for Amount field. Its still checking 4 consecutive number (amount) but if you need to consider more like 6 consecutive Numbers, just tell me. I will make some changes in code.

Comment: still wrong, you can't substring amount from other amount, we do not know what would be the result
i resolve the issue, now it's working correctly, check this link
[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f8e60628d331f61a513181672fe7e79)